# Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, navbar

So i'm learning css online and found this piece of code a bit confusing due to the fact that nothing changes in the output if i remove the " .dropbtn " class, why is it placed there alongside " li a " and why does deleting it has no impact on the output? Help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks! Here's the piece of code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need a [mcve]

Comment: updated the code, the entire code is added now please check

Comment: since the element with the class `dropbtn` matches the selector `li a` the rules still apply, in this case having the class is redundant, but in a real world example the dropdown button might be additionally styled (with an after-element showing an arrow for example). In that case the dedicated class would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element with the class `dropbtn` matches the selector `li a`:

```
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
</li>
```

so the same rules for `li a` apply to this element.
Since all existing rules in this case are using both selectors `li a, .dropbtn`, removing the class doesn't change its styling and is therefore redundant.

**BUT** in a real world example you might have additional styling which should only apply to a dropdown-entry of your navigation (e.g.: with an after-element showing an arrow for example). In that case the dedicated class would make sense.

Furthermore using the `.dropbtn` selector alongside the `li a` selectors make sure, that even if the `.dropbtn` is not of type `a`, the same rules apply as for the other navigation elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,  .dropbtn{
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropbtn {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
 }

.dropbtn::after {
  content: 'v';
  color: red;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```